# Unable to rearrange the Co-ordinates of an Ellipse after rotation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have drawn an Ellipse. I have 8 handles to it.

The handles are TopLeft, MidTop,TopRight, MidLeft, MidRight, BottomLeft, MidBottom, BottomRight.

Whenever a user hovers on any of these handles cursor gets displayed. For displaying the cursor I have referred MS-WORD shape ellipse.

My problem arrives when I roatate or I make a mirror image of an ellipse. I am not able to rearrange the Co-ordinates, hence the cursors are not displayed properly.

Please Help.

Note: Please open MS-WoRD.
Goto "INSERT"
Select "SHAPPES"
In that select "Ellipse" shape.
Draw it.
If you click on it you will see 8 points surrounding ellipse shape. Those are called handles. If you hover your mouse on any of the handle check the cursor display. Cursor display is depending the handle.
I need to implement the same functionality as it is in MS-WORD in VC++. .

EDIT - Added information below from comments:

The problem is with rearranging the coordinates after I rotate. If I roatate the ellipse slightly towards the right (try in MS-WoRD). Which point do i consider as Top-Left? I tried to rearrange with the above code. But it didnt work for many cases. Getting the top-left point after I rotate the ellipse is the main big problem i am facing right now.

```
struct SortingFunction 
{ 
    bool operator()(const CRect& a, const CRect& b) 
    { 
        if (a.left == b.left) 
            return a.top <= b.top; else return a.left < b.left; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you having trouble arranging the orientation of the cursor, or performing the transformation on the ellipse coordinates?  What have you got so far?  How are you storing the coordinates?

Comment: The main problem is with the rearranging of coordinates of handles after i rotate the ellipse. Cursor is displayed depending on the handle.

Comment: I believe it's usually performed using matrix transformations.  These http://www.mathman.biz/html/rotations_with_matrices.html and http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/InformationAboutEllipses.pdf may be useful.  This SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086968/elliptical-rotation-matrix has an approach in it's question that might work for you.  It depends how you're doing the rotation.  I would imagine DirectX has some helper stuff for doing this for example, but at the moment, your question isn't detailed enough for anything but guesses / possible directions.

Comment: I have updated the question ..Please check it..

Comment: From C++, you can invoke COM automation, against MS-Word, to run the command: 'Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementRotation 90#', where 90# is the degrees rotation.  I strongly suspect this isn't the answer you're looking for, although I could be wrong.

Comment: People generally won't write all of your code for you, particularly when they don't know what your code currently looks like.  To improve your chances of getting an answer, you should consider editing your question to include.  Currently I can draw an ellipse (using XXX function).  I’m storing the coordinates/size etc of the ellipse in the following structure.  I’m trying to let the user rotate the ellipse (include what is centre of rotation).  And ideally, I have this code XXX, which doesn’t do what I want because XXX.

Comment: The problem is with rearranging the coordinates after i rotate, If i roatate the ellipse slightly towards right (try in MS-WoRD). Which point do i consider as Top-Left? I tried to rearrange with the above code. But it dint work for many cases. Getting the top-left point after I rotate the ellipse is the main big problem i am facing right now. struct SortingFunction
{  
 bool operator()(const CRect& a, const CRect& b)
    {
        if (a.left == b.left)
            return a.top <= b.top;
        else
            return a.left < b.left;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Handles are also points, all you need to do is to identify the amount of rotation ellipse has gone to and rotate the handles with that rotation.